# fobs4jmf doesn't work in executable jar

Tags: java, jmf

I have created a project in eclipse which is dependant on the jmf and fobs4jmf external jar. I have included the relevant jars to the classpath and when i run my project though eclipse it works fine.

However when I export my project to runnable jar there was several problems. At first it didn't work. But I managed with that by adding images and needed files to jar and updating a MANIFEST.MF file. It worked but when I want to play different files wchich was playing in eclipse with this project it turned out that my program uses only jmf and ignores fobs4jmf. I added to jar all libaries including fobs4jmf and jmf. Also jmf.properties.
A cmd reports that  failed to realize: com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine....
I'm sure that it is problem with fobs4jmf because files with .mp3 extension work and also movies with codecs which are used in jmf work.

Has anyone else had similar problems when including fobs4jmf in a jar, and if so how did you solve it?

Comment: Are you creating one final Jar, or many?